# How to get the "Restricted File Growth" parameter on SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performancecounter

When adding a file to a filegroup, you can restrict the file growth by a certain size.  Is there a way to either query the DB for it? Or get it through performance counter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
--  Deprecated systable
Select  [Filename],
        Size,
        MaxSize,
        Growth
From    sys.sysfiles

--  Replacement system view
Select  physical_name,
        Size,
        max_size,
        growth
From    sys.database_files
```

MaxSize is the growth limit.

Comment: @BogdanSahlean Good call, added the new replacement view.

Comment: The OP should switch the accepted answer to the one below. It is more comprehensive.